# PHP Check if user is logged in with a function

Tags: php, function, authentication

I'm working on a website and the index page checks if the user is logged in or not with this piece of code:

```
if (!$_SESSION['login'] && $_SESSION['login'] == "") {
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/login/");
} elseif ($_SESSION['login'] == 1) {
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/main/");
}
```

But I want it to look cleaner, then I started wondering if was possible to achieve something like this with a function:

```
checklogin($_SESSION['login']);
```

I don't have much experience with functions, so i'm sorry if my question looks stupid, so thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't worry, both snippets you posted are perfectly valid. It's up to you how to structure your code and where to put the logic. But it must be *somewhere*. So if you just want that function (as in the second example), the logic from the previous example will have to be *inside* that function. It can't just go away.

You should re-use an existing authentication framework whenever possible, because, really, it's complex. For example, take a look at https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Auth which is both framework-agnostic and database-agnostic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
if(check_login()) {
  echo 'You are in!';
} else {
    header('Location: login.php');
    exit;
}

function check_login () {
    if(isset($_SESSION['login'] && $_SESSION['login'] != '') {
       return true;
    } else {
       false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use [`empty`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php):

```
if ( empty($_SESSION['login']) ) {
    include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/login/");
} else {
    include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/main/");
}
```

Or condense it:

```
include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].(empty($_SESSION['login']) ? "/login/" : "/main/");
```

Answer (score 2):

There is what you need:

```
function userCheck()
{
    return (isSet($_SESSION['login']) && $_SESSION['login']);
}

if(userCheck())
    include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/main/");
else
    include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/login/");
```

Answer (score 1):

Disregarding the fact of whether or not your approach makes sense, I think this would do what you expect:

```
function checklogin($login){
      if (!$login && $login == "") {
          include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/path/");
      }
}


// **** call to the function

       checklogin($_SESSION['login']);  

// ****
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function:

```
function checklogin() {
  return (isset($_SESSION['login'])) ? true : false;
}
```

then on pages you want to check whether the user is logged in or not, you can:

```
if(checklogin() === true){
  //here you would put what you want to do if the user is logged in
} else {
  //this would be executed if user isn't logged in
  header('Location: protected.php');
  exit();
  //the above would redirect the user
}
```